# How to install cryptsetup 2.1.0 on Debian Stetch? (not in backports)

Tags: debian, cryptsetup, arm64

How should I go about installing `cryptsetup 2.1.0` on Debian stretch? It's not in `stretch-backports` so I'd like to know what's the best way to go about this. I'm on ARM64 (ayufan-rock64 debian stretch image)

Kernel release is `4.4.167-1213-rockchip-ayufan-g34ae07687fce`

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to backport the package yourself:

- install some useful tools, and a build dependency we’ll need later (I’m assuming you have `stretch-backports` enabled already):

  ```
  sudo apt install devscripts
  sudo apt install -t stretch-backports debhelper
  ```
- retrieve the source packages we need, `cryptsetup` and one of its build-dependencies, `argon2`:

  ```
  dget -u http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/argon2/argon2_0~20171227-0.2.dsc
  dget -u http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/cryptsetup/cryptsetup_2.1.0-5+deb10u1.dsc
  ```
- create packages representing the build dependencies:

  ```
  mk-build-deps argon2-0~20171227/debian/control
  mk-build-deps cryptsetup-2.1.0/debian/control
  ```
- install `argon2`’s build dependencies:

  ```
  sudo apt install ./argon2-build-deps_*_all.deb
  ```
- build `argon2`:

  ```
  cd argon2-0~20171227
  dch --bpo
  ```

  (this will open an editor, with a modified `debian/changelog` ready for you to edit; delete the second line starting with an asterisk, save the file and close the editor)

  ```
  dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
  ```
- install the `argon2` packages we need:

  ```
  cd ..
  sudo dpkg -i libargon2-dev_0~20171227-0.2~bpo9+1_*.deb libargon2-1_0~20171227-0.2~bpo9+1_*.deb
  ```
- install `cryptsetup`’s other build dependencies:

  ```
  sudo apt install ./cryptsetup-build-deps_*_all.deb
  ```
- build `cryptsetup`:

  ```
  cd cryptsetup-2.1.0
  dch --bpo
  dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
  ```

You can now remove the `build-deps` packages and any packages which become auto-removable as a result, along with the packages we installed separately (`devscripts`, `debhelper`, `libargon2-dev`).